# probability of a certain presidential ancestry

Tags: probability

A common phrase in the U.S. is that anyone can become president.

What are the odds, assuming the above comment is correct, that 42 of the 43 U.S. presidents are directly related to King John of England?

Comment: Particularly in the old days, rich powerful men were far more likely to pass on their genes than poor men.

Comment: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10433/were-all-but-one-of-the-us-presidents-descended-from-king-john-of-england ...but the question hasn't been answered.

Comment: I couldn't care less whether the statement is true or not, whether its a conspiracy question or not. I am interested in the odds.